# Mapping Role to static values

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Continuing my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38553853/3932049), the accepted answer works perfectly.
However, I only want to have a few roles in my database, say:

table: *Roles*

```
Id | Role
---------------
1  | AccountOwner
2  | AccountAdmin
3  | AccountUser
```

The accepted answer in the question creates a new row in Roles every time a user is registered for an account. Is there any way I can request the Identity system to use the existent roles in the database? Considering the code:

```
public static async Task<bool> AddAccountAsync(this MyContext context, MyModel model)
{
    try
    {
        Role role = new Role(TrackerRole.Owner);
        Account account = new Account(model.AccountCurrency, model.AccountName, model.Description);
        UserAccount uc = new UserAccount
        {
            User = model.User,
            Account = account,
            Role = role
        };
        account.UserAccounts.Add(uc);
        context.Accounts.Add(account);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        model.User.UserAccounts.Add(uc);
        return true;
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        // LOG
    }
    return false;
}
```

If possible, I'd like to remove the Role class entirely and substitute it for an Enum.

Comment: If you want to substitute it to an enum, the role entity is no longer needed, as is the Role table in the database. Just have the Role property be of type Role (enum) and it will persist as an int to the db.
However, this leads to design flaws were you need to update code to add other roles for the future.

Comment: @stefchri All roles have been taken into account already, so that may work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to substitute it to an enum, the role entity is no longer needed, as is the Role table in the database. Just have the Role property be of type Role (enum) and it will persist as an int to the db. However, this leads to design flaws were you need to update code to add other roles for the future.

About only having the three roles and not adding them needlessly every time:
Get the correct role from the db (`var role = Context.Roles.Where(...).FirstOrDefault()`) and put this into the role property of the useraccount. This way you will be sure all the uac's will point to the correct instances of the roles.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. However, I'd like to know how to remove the Role class entirely, since the Identity system requires a "Role" class

Comment: Completely dropping it will not be possible I think. See question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38612771/is-it-possible-to-save-a-role-with-enum-parameter-using-identity

Comment: I decided to just leave the role class empty and make the RoleStore 'throw new NotImplementedException' for every method, thanks though